# Not able to understand how the domEvent works

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Scenario:

I have a RadCombobox and I have attached functions to most of the events. 
One event of the combobox is OnClientBlur and I am using this to check whether value in Combo is "Unassigned" or not. If it is "Unassigned" I need to cancel the onblur event and keep the focus on to the same combo.

[image: Dropdown with value Unassigned]

This is the javascript which I has been used to cancel the event.

```
if (sender.get_text() === "Unassigned") {
      eventArgs.get_domEvent().preventDefault();
      return false;
}
```

Problem:

When the user tabs out first time of the ComboBox the event gets cancelled and the focus stays on the same combo box (in this case it is the 3rd Combo).

But when the user hits the tab button again the focus moves to the next control.

When I debugged the code I found that when the user first hits the tab button, following line works

```
      eventArgs.get_domEvent().preventDefault();
```

I can see the preventDefault function, see following snapshot.
[image: Has function preventDefault]

but when the user hits the tab button again I get an error and cannot see preventDefault function, see following snapshot

[image: preventDefault not found]

I am not able to understand what is going wrong here. Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, revolves around the difference between MouseEvents and KeyEvents. And also the way Telerik implement the `OnClientBlur` event. As far as it doesn't point to a specific type of browser event, each time it gets triggered

As you see in the first snapshot you got `clientX` and `clientY`, which means your `OnClientBlur` derived from a `MouseEvent`.

Whereas in the second one you got `altKey`, `altLeft`, and also there is no `button` property, which means that this one is a `KeyEvent`.

The other point here is as you have these fields in the output:

```
e.bookmarks
e.behaviorPart
e.behaviorCookie
```

Means you are using one of the old versions of IE4+ to IE7 or IE8, which they have `cancelBubble` instead of `preventDefault`.

Sometimes events are not `cancelable`, and using `event.cancelable` you can make sure if the current event is `cancelable` or not.

At the end to fix you code you can simply do this:

```
if (sender.get_text() === "Unassigned") {
    var domEvent = eventArgs.get_domEvent();
    if(domEvent.cancelable){
        if(typeof(domEvent.preventDefault)==="function")
            domEvent.preventDefault();
        else
            domEvent.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        //you can not cancel the event, do something else to make it manageable
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post. I am facing one issue. I get `domEvent.cancelable` as undefiend, so definetly I cannot cancel the event, in this case should I focus on some control and then focus back on the combo? Cause I do not want to allow the user to move ahead untill he selects a proper value.